# Swift - When receiving a silent notification decide whether to show an alert or not

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, remote-notifications, silent-notification

I need your help,

I wanted to ask you 3 simple questions, where one goes in consequence of the other.
Basically I want to limit to users the number of notifications they receive. Since it is a group chat and they are constantly receiving push.
The idea is that I will get a push silent from a group, if this group did not send any push for 30 minutes, what I will do is show the push, if on the contrary less than 30 minutes ago we do not show the push.
And that is why, I wanted to `regumber the following:

1. Is it possible to receive a silent push notification afterwards
   to decide whether to display the alert or not?
2. If the answer is affirmative, how can it be done?
3. How do I do it when the app is in Background?

Thank you :)

Comment: 1. yes. 2.easy. 3.easy

Comment: Can you explain step 2 and 3 with an example from you or the Internet? Because I do not see anything. Thank you :) !

Comment: https://medium.com/@lucasgoesvalle/custom-push-notification-with-image-and-interactions-on-ios-swift-4-ffdbde1f457

Comment: 1 - Can I listen to silent notification from the Appdelegate on remoteNotification? 2 - Can I decide in the app kill whether or not to show silent notifications depending on the time that has passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)

and 
[Modifying Content in Newly Delivered Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications)